# Constructing a sequence of bounded linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

How to construct a sequence of linear functionals $\{T_n\}:L^{\infty}([0,1]) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\{T_n\}$ is uniformly bounded. Also, there's no linear functional $T\in (L^{\infty}([0,1]))^*$ and subsequence $n_k$ such that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} T_{n_k} (f) = T(f), \quad \forall f \in L^{\infty}([0,1]).
$$
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3578970/show-that-a-set-of-linear-functionals-on-l-infty-is-not-weakly-sequential).

Comment: Your title is not in line with your question.

Comment: @Ruy Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my title.

Comment: Since the elements of the stone-cech compactification can be viewed as ;inear functionals on $L^\infty$, the question is answered by https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138161/non-trivial-convergent-sequence-in-stone-%C4%8Cech-compactification-of-mathbbn